# How can l delete my app data after deletion in home screen?

Tags: android

Having trouble to install new apps after deletion in home screen.the app data still there in phone memory.so l want to know how to free up the memory.

Comment: Do you have an example ? What have you tried ? One line questions like this, we consider *low quality*. Please take a moment to see the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the **Settings** of your phone.
2. Select the **Apps** option
3. Choose your app
4. Select **Storage** option
5. Choose **Clear data** to erase app data